# GeometryReader not working inside LazyVGrid

Tags: swift, swiftui, lazyvgrid

I have the following code

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var items = ["1", "2", "3", "4"]
    
    var body: some View {
        LazyVGrid(columns: [GridItem(), GridItem()]) {
            ForEach(items, id: \.self) { item in
                GeometryReader { geometry in
                    Text(item)
                        .frame(width: geometry.size.width, height: geometry.size.width)
                        .background(.red)
                }
            }
        }.background(.green)
    }
}
```

and I am getting the following screen

[image]

What I expected is 4 square grid items but as you can see the grid items are stacked on top of each other and LazyVGrid is not resizing which you can see the green colored

If I remove GeometryReader and set frame(width: height:) to some static number it's working but I would like to set it dynamically based on screen size

Comment: "based on screen size" in what way exactly? Can you describe exactly the relation between the frame of the text and the screen size?

Comment: @Sweeper I want two texts in each row, regardless of screen size

Comment: That's the default behaviour. You don't need a `GeometryReader` or a `frame` modifier. Have you tried that?